# select an img which does not contain word in src

Tags: jquery, selector

If i have the 4 images

```
<img src="img/tracker/"/>
<img src="img/tracked/"/>
<img src="img/tracking/"/>
<img src="img/track/"/>
```

how can i select the last 3 images by using src does not contain I have tried `$(img:not([src*="/tracker/"]))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('img:not([src*="/tracker/"])')...
```

- The selector should be a string.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8pHXw/2)

Comment: I was assuming that was what he tried (i.e. a quoted string) as the alternative would throw a syntax error...

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that you can't match the slashes?

Comment: @Prestaul. No, it was a mistake, I thought it was "\" and in that case it's need to be escaped. but it's `/` so it's fine.

Comment: cool. I was about to be disappointed and I'm not used to being disappointed with jQuery. :)